# Chartbreak on specific row count (large datasets)

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

Is there a possibility to create a new chart if a specific number of rows is reached?
Lets say i have 150 entries in my dataset, but the chart is only readable with 50 entries each. 
How could i do that?

PS: To the Editor i'm working with dynamic-reports which use jasper-reports.

Comment: I ended up splitting the datasource adding it to an arraylist and create the amount of reports in the arraylist, and finally stick them together manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the following workaround to this problem.

The max size of the DataSources in the list specifies the max rows per chart.
This solution consists of two classes:

- The Concenator (Observer)
- The ReportGenerator (Runnable or Thread,
  Observable)

Visio sketch of the concenator:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMmvC.png

The Concenator first generates a list of DataSources with each having a maximum length.
Than for each DataSource in the list a ReportGenerator will be started, he also will get the pagenumber (for final sorting after collection).
The Concenator waits until every reportpage is delivered.
Whenn every page is collected the concenator sorts the pages according to the number and then stick them together page by page.

PS: I have an visio sketch ready but less reputation for posting it directly.